# How to backup Chrome extension data on a mac?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I am using a google chrome extension called JScript Tricks. This extension lets me to manipulate webpage with jQuery injection. The challenge is my scripts for each website cannot be exported from the extension, and the scripts are not synchronized over the cloud. So for each script I have to recreate on a second computer, and it will take a few hours to go through 50 some scripts. I am wondering if there is a location where chrome stores the extension settings.

Note: this is not where the extension is stored, which is at "~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Extensions"

This is where the extension calls for "chrome.storage" method, and chrome stores them in a secret database (see the documentation of the API at https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage). I wonder if any hackers already figure out how to access chrome's local storage for extensions. Thanks.

Comment: Is copy paste a viable option for your scripts? When editing the script, isn't it just like a text editor?

Comment: Copying the entire user profile should do it. Otherwise to find the cache file that stores the data, update the scripts, and check file modification dates.